# WooCommerce search products by tag or description Query Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to write the custom query to search product by its description. By default the WooCommerce search doesn't include the searching by description. I am using the `query_posts` function to get products. Here is my code:

```
$args = array(
    's'                   => $search_keyword,
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_query'          => array(
       array(
        'key'     => '_visibility',
        'value'   => array( 'search', 'visible' ),
        'compare' => 'IN'
        )
      )
   );
$products = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to search the product description, you are going to have to search the `post_content`. I don't think you'll be able to do that using `get_posts()` or `WP_Query()`. The only way to do that is to write a custom SQL query.

For your example, you'd need something like the following:

```
function enhanced_product_search( $keyword ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Manually build SQL query and get results (this query will return only IDs)
    $search_results = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT posts.ID 
            FROM ssod_posts AS posts
                LEFT JOIN ssod_postmeta AS meta ON meta.post_id = posts.ID
            WHERE posts.post_type = 'product'
                AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND meta.meta_key = '_visibility'
                AND meta.meta_value IN ('search', 'visible')
                AND ( posts.post_title LIKE '%{$keyword}%' OR posts.post_content LIKE '%{$keyword}%' );"
        ),
        'ARRAY_N'
    );

    $products = [];

    // Loop over search results to get products from their IDs
    foreach ( $search_results as $result ) {
        $products[] = wc_get_product( $result[0] );
    }

    return $products;
}
```